# android crashlytics shows a crash but doesn't show where in my classes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, crashlytics

I'm using crashlytics to monitor my app, and I can see some users are having this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:181)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$3$1.invokeSuspend(SafeCollector.common.kt:1)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.invokeSuspend(SafeCollector.kt:1)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:100)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:100)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:26)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:26)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(HandlerContext.java:169)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

the thing is that this logs doesn't point to any place in my app's code.
it looks like i have some concurrent array modification, but i cannot figure out where it can be.

I do use proguard rules and minify enables, if it matters. i would still assume that the crash would point to somewhere in my package.

any ideas how I can investiagte this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest find at all places, were you use `.asFlow()` or other flow builders in project, wrap all those flows' `collect` or other terminal operators like `first()` or `single()` in try/catch and add a defining log in catch.